# How can I get the "Many" side of an entity to show up in the API call result without running into Jackson recursive errors?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jackson

I have two entities, UserAccount and Post. There's a one to many relationship between them.

In my UserAccount class, I have:

```
//other UserAccount details
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "posterAccount")
private List<Post> posts;
```

And in my Post class, I have:

```
// Post details here
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountId")
private Account posterAccount;
```

If I try to make a call to any end point that uses Account or post, I get: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

If I add @JsonIgnore to the ManyToOne mapping, the exception goes away and the program works.

## **Here's the issue:**

When I do the api call to get a post, this is what I get back:

```
{
    "postId": 1,
    "title": "Title of Post 1",
    "body": "Body of Post 1",
}
```

But I want something like this:

```
{
    "postId": 1,
    "title": "Title of Post 1",
    "body": "Body of Post 1",
    "posterAccount": {
                 // UserAccount info stuff here
     }
}
```

But to get something like what's above, I need to remove @JsonIgnore. Removing @JsonIgnore will cause the recursive problem to happen again.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR : There is a pair of Jackson annotations designed to solve this specific case, namely [@JsonManagedReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) and [@JsonBackReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html). The field annotated with `@JsonBackReference` is not serialised in this case.

This issue is a nice warning bell that you might want to reconsider your architecture, or at least how you design your JPA entities. If requirements for your REST endpoints influence how you design your data access, then maybe it is time to introduce some sort of Resource / DTO / whatever-you-want-to-call-them classes so that you can do the mapping between the two layers more explicit?

At the very least I would think if I really need both the `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` annotations. In most cases I had having just one of them sufficed. If needed I could always find the other side of a relationship using JPQL.

Comment: I've seen `@JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference` when I was looking for how to fix it. I simply forgot to remove @JsonIgnore when I used it  I've fixed it, thanks